# Performance static array vs pointer to an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

A pointer will always have a little overhead over a static array because to use it you first need to load the pointer address into a registry (I'm talking of assembly).

For example:

```
   var_resul = var_dynamic[var_index];
009D13F3  movsx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-45h] 
009D13F7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
009D13FA  mov         dl,byte ptr [ecx+eax] 
009D13FD  mov         byte ptr [ebp-51h],dl 

   var_resul = var_static[var_index];
009D1400  movsx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-45h] 
009D1404  mov         cl,byte ptr [ebp+eax*4-3Ch] 
009D1408  mov         byte ptr [ebp-51h],cl
```

Is there any way to fix this in c++? I'm programming a chess engine and every speed gain is important.
I suppose that this requires to change the assembly instructions dynamically on runtime to point to the allocated memory region, but may be such feature exists, even if it breaks the portability of the code. I'm using visual c++.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me you haven't profiled and are just attempting to optimize prematurely.

Comment: How do you know that's slower?  You do realise modern CPUs execute instructoins in parallel, so you can't just count the lines...?  Have you benchmarked it and found it's significant in your chess program?  What are your profiling measurements?  Hardly seems equivalent code anyway - one array is of 32-bit values, the other 8-bit.

Comment: I really really doubt this is where your program is spending the majority of its time. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law

Comment: Your opening sentence of each paragraph are together a contradiction. If your first sentence is true (and it generally is), then there is nothing to fix. Static arrays do what you seek, so use them if you can. Not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: I understand that your responses are standard ones, and I like them in some situations, but I'm not searching such types of reasonable comments/solutions. I'm searching for crazy or hacky ideas. All it's for fun. Sure someone has thought about it. Thanks anyway.